# OWASP markup formatter not supported in Jenkins 2.263.2

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have been trying to Install Active choice parameter which has dependency on OWASP Markup formatter but it is failing in installing stating OWASP markup formatter require update to 2.0 (currently on 1.5). Also I am not able to update OWASP markup Formatter. Jenkins version that I am using is 2.263.2.
Is it jenkins compatibility issue with OWASP markup formatter ? Is there a workaround for that ?
Or is there any replacement plugin for Active choice parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Gotta love that your problem involves 2 plugins whose names no longer align [Active Choices: uno choice](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) and [OWASP Markup Formatter: antisamy-markup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/antisamy-markup-formatter/).

**TL;DR**: install the older version if you are OK with the risk:

[Active Choices docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/#documentation) excerpts show:

- Version 2.5.4 (2021/02/28)
  JENKINS-64962: Fix radio buttons and check boxes not being displayed. The height in CSS was calculated with JS to 0 (zero). That was due to recent workaround for table-to-divs (JENKINS-62806). We may have to inspect more of the code that was changed, and also confirm the table-to-divs is working as expected. This fix was relased quickly to give users a fix ASAP.
- Version 2.5.3 (2021/02/24)
  SECURITY-2192: Fix XSS vulnerability
- Version 2.5.2 (2021/02/21)
  JENKINS-62806: active-choices plugin may break with tables-to-divs.
  Version 2.5.1 (2020/10/17)
- Version 2.5 (2020/10/13)
  SECURITY-1954 - CVE-2020-2289: Active Choices Plugin 2.4 and earlier does not escape the name and description of build parameters. This results in a stored cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability exploitable by attackers with Job/Configure permission. Active Choices Plugin 2.5 escapes the name of build parameters and applies the configured markup formatter to the description of build parameters.
  SECURITY-2008 - CVE-2020-2290 : Active Choices Plugin 2.4 and earlier does not escape List and Map return values of sandboxed scripts for Reactive Reference Parameter. This results in a stored cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerability exploitable by attackers with Job/Configure permission. This issue is caused by an incomplete fix for SECURITY-470. Active Choices Plugin 2.5 escapes all legal return values of sandboxed scripts.
- Version 2.4 (2020/07/09)
  JENKINS-62215: antisamy-markup-formatter-plugin v2.0 filters input fields from uno-choice plugin. In this version we have added a built-in markup formatter in the plug-in (NB: not available in Jenkins as a markup formatter) that allows for input, textarea, select, and option HTML tags). The issue was found and fixed by Andrew Potter @apottere (thanks!)
- Version 2.3 (2020/05/16)
  JENKINS-62317: Upgrade dependencies pre 2.3 release (Jenkins LTS 2.204 now, Java 8, script-security 1.72, antisamy-markup-formatter 2.0, no more powermockito in tests, fixing spot bugs issues)

So that mean you need antisamy-markup-formatter:2.0+ for uno-choice:2.3+

[OWASP release notes](https://plugins.jenkins.io/antisamy-markup-formatter/#releases) excerpts show:

- 2.1
  JENKINS-62176 - Add pre tag to policy additions as it is missing in Sanitizers (#22) 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.markup.Messages.EscapedMarkupFormatter_DisplayName()Ljava/lang/String; (#23)
- 2.0
- 1.8
  bump parent pom (#18)
- 1.7
- 1.6
  Remove dead EbayPolicy (#9) 
  Java 11 readiness: build both on JDK8 and JDK11 (#10) 
  Update to latest 3.43 parent (#11) 
  Add Jenkinsfile (#6) 
  JENKINS-59081 - Include test for jcasc compatibility (#13)

And a [general note](https://plugins.jenkins.io/antisamy-markup-formatter/#documentation):

> The plugin manager contains a slightly misleading warning: While there
> is no "different settings format", OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin 2.0
> reduced the set of allowed elements. Previously defined descriptions
> may no longer look the same. The plugin can be freely upgraded to 2.0
> or downgraded again to 1.8, if necessary.

So, if you are OK with the 3 security vulnerabilities fixed since 2.2, you could choice to install the [older release](https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin#release-notes)  manually (Install via cli: jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins [uno-choice:2.2.2](https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/uno-choice/2.2.2/uno-choice.hpi) or UI upload), which will work with antisamy-markup-formatter:1.5

ps: Why not "not able to update OWASP markup Formatter" ?

Comment: Unable to update "OWASP markup Formatter" from 1.5 to 2.0 or higher because of jenkins version compatibility. Jenkins version used - 2.263.2. Is there a such compatibility issues with jenkins version and owasp markup plugin ?

Comment: 2.263.2 was released 2021-01-13, OWASP 2.1 on 2020-07-01, so  not direct issue. Examine your logs for exact reason you can't u/g OWASP